# Движение игрока SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

```
void update(RenderWindow& window)
    {
        Event event;
        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::W))
        {
            dy = -0.3;
        }
        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::A))
        {
            dx = -0.3;
        }
        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::S))
        {
            dy = 0.3;
        }
        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::D))
        {
            dx = 0.3;
        }
    
        x += dx;
        y += dy;

        dx = dy = 0;

        EntitySprite.setPosition(x, y);

        window.draw(EntitySprite);
        
    }
};
```

При движении описанном в таком коде, игрок движется угловато: либо влево, либо вверх, либо вправо, либо вниз, ли по диагонали под углом 45 градусов при нажатии двух кнопок вместе, например S и D. Можно ли этот угол сделать более плавным, чтобы само движение осуществлялось не только влево, вправо, по диагонали и т.д? Моих знаний по геометрии здесь не хватает, поэтому прошу у вас помощь).

Comment: используйте больше кнопок, что бы задать более точные углы, используйте джойстик/геймпад, используйте  a/d для поворота на несколько градусов, а w соответственно будет передвигать вперед.

Comment: я имел в виду сгладить это угол при повороте для движения по диагонали, чтоб он не сразу по диагонали двигался, а с немного округленной плавной траекторией движения

Comment: тогда Вам нужно две переменные "текущий угол" и "желаемый угол". Стрелочки меняют желаемый угол (тут все относительно просто). А в цикле обновления, раз в какое то время (подбираете экспериментально), текущий угол уменьшаете/увеличиваете в сторону желаемого. И готово.

Comment: не нужны там никакие углы! Я попробовал сделать через ускорение и дельта ускорение по осям абсцисс и ординат, и все сработало как надо

Comment: значит я неверно понял Вашу задачу

Comment: Ну все равно спасибо вам что обратили внимание на мой вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Я сделал это так, добавив ускорение и дельта ускорение, дав возможность игроку контролировать не скорость, а ускорение!

```
void update(RenderWindow& window) 
{
    float decceleration = 0.3;

    if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::W))
    {
        accelerationY -= decceleration;
    }
    if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::S))
    {
        accelerationY += decceleration;
    }
    if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::A))
    {
        accelerationX -= decceleration;
    }
    if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::D))
    {
        accelerationX += decceleration;
    }

    dx += accelerationX;
    dy += accelerationY;

    speed = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    if (speed > maxSpeed)
    {
        dx *= maxSpeed / speed;
        dy *= maxSpeed / speed;
    }

    x += dx;
    y += dy;

    dx *= 0.9;
    dy *= 0.9;

    accelerationX = 0;
    accelerationY = 0;

    EntitySprite.setPosition(x, y);
    window.draw(EntitySprite);

}
```